# How to check whether audio file exists or not in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<audio controls>

  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

I want to display audio tag only if audio file exists . Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: You want to check audio file exist or not in the folder?

Comment: for an example test.mp3 doesnt exits  at that time audio tag must be hidden . audio tag must  display only file exists. is it possbile do it ?

Comment: I got ans <audio controls src="horse.mp3" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'">

Answer (score 1):

Make an ajax request to the audio file you need.The response will let you know if the file exists or not

```
$.ajax({
url:'test.mp3',
type:'HEAD',
error: function()
{
    //file does not exist
},
success: function()
{
    //file exists
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check file exists

```
  <?php 
    if (file_exists('test.mp3')) {
    ?>
        <audio controls>
         <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I got the ans <audio controls src="horse.mp3" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'">.. Thanks a lot